# Error in sending 2nd text from "twilio rest api"

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, twilio

I am sending messages form my application. But, when sending 2nd text from application, then the message is not sent. I don't know why?
here is the code

```
for (int i = 0; i <= numbr.Length; i++)
{
    var statusurl = "";
    var nums = numbr[i];
    var delivery = twilioRestClient.SendSmsMessage("+13082242885", nums, msg);
    var sq = delivery.Sid;
    statusurl = delivery.Uri.ToString();
    //store statusurl array to db
}
```

Help me in getting out of the problem. First message is sent easily and received in very short time.

***Answer***
[image]
the api is not sending 2nd text because i am using twilio Trial account which only allow me to send message to my own verified number
https://www.twilio.com/docs/errors/21608

Comment: Sending messages how? We can't find out the code hidden into SendSmsMessage!

Comment: What is inside -> SendSmsMessage

Comment: `SendSmsMessage` is a function of twilio rest api

Answer (score 2):

Twilio Trial accounts send sms to only verified numbers log into your account in twilio portal and verify that number to which you are sending sms. Twilio will call on that number and will ask you type a pin code.
Hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

Twilio evangelist here.

Couple of suggestions.

1. Check to see if Twilio is returning an error by checking to see if `deilvery.RestException` is null.
2. Check the Twilio [log](https://www.twilio.com/user/account/log/sms) in your dashboard to see if Twilio says its sending the second message.

Hope that helps.

Comment: yes delivery is throwing Null exception 
and no sign of 2nd message on twilio dashboard

Comment: OK, as a next step I would use an HTTP logging tool like Fiddler to see what is actually being sent to Twilio, and what its responses are.